# Validate my understanding on Express Routes

Tags: node.js, express

Actually, before I get into the question, when I do anything like

`const app = express()`

`app` is an instance of the entire express module right? Meaning, when I do `app.route`, **route** is it an Express method right or a NodeJS method, since Node has `.route` as well? Anyways... I just wanted to double check this.

```
app.route('/games')
    .post(postGame)
    .get(getGames);

app.route('/games/:id');
    .get(getGame)
    .delete(deleteGame);
```

Is this the same as... and if not... why would one choose one over the other?

```
app.get('/games');
app.post('/games');
app.get('/games/:id');
app.delete('games/:id');
```

Sorry, it's just been a while since I have used Express, and couldn't find anything about this *specific* problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app is an instance of the entire express module right?

Yes, the app object is create by calling the top-level `express()` function exported by the Express module. That set the default http headers, render options.... and wrap the http node module:

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

You can see more in the [source code here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/9722202df964bfbfc0f579e4baeb5a4e1b43b344/lib/express.js) (really readble)

> route is it an Express method right or a NodeJS method

Route is an express object and nodeJs don't provide a routing system like express.

And for your example yes it's totally the same. They stores the handlers function in the same `this._router.route`

Comment: Thank you, I think I should start investing time into reading source code. I feel like I need to build an npm module so I can understand to read it better :)

Comment: @dsomel21 Can you valid the answer for close the question pls :)